# Размер проекта VS C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Проблема с VS11 - после компиляции простого проекта на С++ (CLR) создается два файла, занимающих значительное пространство - *SQL Server Compact Edition Database File* и *Intellisense Precompiled Header File*. Полностью выключать поддержку Intellisense очень не хотелось бы.

Вопрос - как отключить создание этих файлов и насколько это будет критично?

Comment: эммм...CLR???

Comment: А зачем отключать? Они не мешают, лежат себе, помогают компилятору, каши не просят. Или у вас проблемы с местом на диске?

---
@DreamChild: Угу, это Microsoft'овская модификация C++ под .NET (не знаю, зачем она понадобилась автору вопроса).

Comment: @VladD ну тогда CLI)

Comment: @DreamChild: а, точно!  
@jouravleff: Эти файлы не нужно выкладывать в git, и не нужно копировать при сохранении на внешний носитель. Точно так же, как и содержимое каталогов `bin`, `obj`, `Debug` и `Release`. Просто напишите скрипт для копирования, который будет копировать только нужное. А для git есть `.gitignore`.

Comment: Но всё-таки хотелось бы узнать, как отключать...
2DreamChild: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jpsvxk2sr75di21/52428.JPG

Comment: Ну, это внутренние файлы Visual Studio, отключить их, даже если это возможно, значит выкинуть какую-то часть функциональности. Если очень не хочется писать скрипты, попробуйте переместить эти файлы: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7707083/276994

Comment: @jouravleff язык называется C++/CLI, а приведенный вами скриншот свидетельствует не о названии языка, а о том, что проект на этой модификации C++  работает "поверх" CLR.

Comment: @DreamChild Захотелось изучить новые библиотеки, руководствовался наличием книг и наставлениями преподавателей. Самому больше нравится qt, но с ним пока трудновато.

Comment: @jouravleff: пожалуйста! Всё же, если хотите посмотреть в сторону .NET, очень **не** рекомендую C++/CLI, он необычайно сложен, нелогичен и уродлив. Либо переходите на C#, либо оставайтесь на чистом C++ без CLI.

Comment: @jouravleff  мой вам самый искренний совет - бросайте вы эти глупости (не изучение новых библиотек, а конкретно Managed C++). Лучше уж займитесь либо чистым С++, либо C#, если есть желание работать с .NET. C++/CLI мало того, что коряв, но еще и мало востребован

Answer (score 1):

Генерацию *Intellisense Precompiled Header File* можно отключить так: Project → Properties → Configuration Properties → C/C++ → Precompiled Headers → Precompiled Header = Not Using Precompiled Header.

С *SQL Server Compact Edition Database File* всё немного сложнее. Вам стоит обратить внимание на [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7707083). Фактически, совсем удалить этот файл нельзя, но можно настроить Visual Studio так, чтобы он создавался в другом месте (там, где не жалко памяти). Делается это таким образом: Tools → Options → Text Editor → C/C++ → Advanced → Fallback Location. Полям "Always Use Fallback Location" и "Do Not Warn If Fallback Location Used" устанавливаете значение *True*, в поле "Fallback Location" вводите, куда будет записываться данный файл для каждого проекта (например, *D:\Temp\VS_temp*).

Answer (score 0):

В настройках проекта можно отключить создание предкомпилированных заголовков
Проект - Свойства - С\С++ - Предварительно скомпилированные заголовки

Они нужны для более быстрой компиляции крупных проектов.